# Valid tag is totally invalid tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Existence of [valid](/questions/tagged/valid) does not hold any merit and it is totally a meta tag for Stack Overflow. Needs to be burninated.

Comment: +1 because you referenced Trogdor.

Comment: [Some of those questions are better tagged as Validation, too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504072/paypal-email-validation).

Comment: -1 because you referenced Trogdor without an appropriate pic. (Just kidding! Mostly...)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Stack Overflow tags and the request is already [status-completed]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's dead, <s>Jim</s> Aziz.  It's now tag number **134** I keep dead daily.

Tag-teamed it with [JoshC](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/232567/joshc).

Comment: If you're going to make a Star Trek reference, please spell `it's` correctly, and not `it'd`.

Comment: speeling us overrratedd.